# PyQt5 QTableWidget signal connector called twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have the following code that populates a QTableWidget:

```
 def populate_phone_table(self):
        dataRows=["Office","Fax","Mobile","Other"]
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.setRowCount(4)
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.setColumnCount(2)
        for ndx,value in enumerate(dataRows):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(value)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            item.setForeground(QColor(0,0,0))
            self.tbl_phone_numbers.setItem(ndx,0,item)
            item = QTableWidgetItem("")
            self.tbl_phone_numbers.setItem(ndx, 1, item)
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1,QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.tbl_phone_numbers.itemChanged.connect(self.update_phone_table)

    def update_phone_table(self,item):
        print(item.text())
        item.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))
```

The problem I am running into is when I edit a column, the connector is being called twice.  I'm not sure if it's the signal firing twice, this is be design or I'm not using the correct signal.  Essesntially, I need the `update_phone_table` method called (once) when a QTableViewItem is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, because in

```
def update_phone_table(self,item):
    print(item.text())
    item.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))
```

`item.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))` changes the item, so `itemChanged()` is emitted again.
If you comment out `item.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))`, you will see `print(item.text())` is printed only once.

If you insist that "the update_phone_table method called (once) when a QTableViewItem is edited", you can block the signal like this:

```
def update_phone_table(self,item):
    print(item.text())
    self.tbl_phone_numbers.blockSignals(True)
    item.setForeground(QColor(255,0,0))
    self.tbl_phone_numbers.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks azalea.  I didn't realize that changing the color would also cause the signal to emit again.  Thanks for your help!